# What's SE's position on linking to scraper-ish sites?

Tags: discussion

I recently approved an edit on [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/18/5489) that removed a dead link from a deleted Stack Overflow article. A search for the question yielded [this](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?service=stackoverflow&question=498698) though...an external page that scraped the content before the post was deleted.

I don't see anything TOO nefarious about the site, but that was one of my first actions with moderator tools so I didn't want to override the edit with a link to that page if that's something that the SE overlords don't like.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Stack Exchange content is available under our [Creative Commons license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/C) except they *must* include attribution.

> You are free:
>
> - to Share— to copy, distribute and transmit the work
> - to Remix — to adapt the work
>
> Under the following conditions:
>
> **Attribution** — You must attribute the work in the manner specified by the author or licensor(but not in any way that suggests that they endorse you or your use of the work).
>
> **Share Alike** — If you alter, transform, or build upon this work, you may distribute the resulting work only under the same or similar license to this one.

You can see a more detailed guide at [the blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/defending-attribution-required/).

In this case, it looks like it should be okay, but I will run it past our internal person who checks for compliance. But, in general, I've linked to caches and Stack Printer when a user didn't have enough reputation to see deleted questions on their site.

Basically: "mirrors" are tolerated until we learn they aren't attributing correctly. Then we send them a notice.